Issues with Detecting Negative Change in AR(1) Model Using CPAT Library
I'm currently working on evaluating the empirical power of the CUSUM, Rényi CUSUM, and Erdős-Darling tests for detecting change points in AR(1) models, specifically focusing on changes in the mean. Below is the code snippet I'm using for this analysis:
library(CPAT)

Test=function(n, nb, beta, ro, alpha, g){
  #### Initialize variables and vectors
  p = 20
  X1 = numeric(n + 2 * p)
  X2 = numeric(n + 2 * p)
  D1 = numeric(n)
  
  prob2 = logical(nb)
  prob3 = logical(nb)
  prob4 = logical(nb)
  
  a = 1:p
  
  # Simulation of the AR(1) model
  for(k in 1:nb){
    E = rnorm(n + 2 * p)
    
    # Simulate AR(1) model before the change point
    X1[1] = rnorm(1)
    for(i in 2:(g + p)){
      X1[i] = ro * X1[i - 1] + E[i]
    }
    
    # Simulate AR(1) model after the change point
    X2[1] = rnorm(1)
    for(i in 2:(n - g + p)){
      X2[i] = (ro + beta / sqrt(n)) * X2[i - 1] + E[(g + p + i - 1)]
    }
    
    X = c(X1[-a], X2[-a])
    
    # Calculate residuals of the model
    D1[1] = X[1] - ro * X1[p]
    for(i in 2:n){
      D1[i] = X[i] - ro * X[i - 1]
    }
    
    # Apply CPAT tests and assess power
    prob2[k] = (CUSUM.test(D1, use_kernel_var = FALSE, stat_plot = FALSE, kernel = "ba", bandwidth = "and")$p.value < alpha)
prob3[k] = (HR.test(D1, kn = sqrt, use_kernel_var = FALSE, stat_plot = FALSE, kernel = "ba", bandwidth = "and")$p.value < alpha)
    prob4[k] = (CPAT::stat_de(X) > CPAT::qdarling_erdos(1 - alpha))
  }
  
  # Compute mean probabilities across simulations
  Ls = list(mean(prob2), mean(prob3), mean(prob4))
  return(Ls)
}

Currently, I'm encountering an issue where the power of the tests is significantly lower than the specified significance level alpha when beta (the change in mean) is negative. This seems counterintuitive.
My Questions:
Could there be any errors in my code contributing to this issue?
How can I ensure that the functions from the CPAT package are correctly applied to accurately determine the power of these tests for detecting negative changes in an AR(1) model?
